# Google Maps Android API v2 : Is there a quick way to know if there is a Marker at a given location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to know if there is a Marker at a given LatLng location. Is there any quick way to do this, or do I need to write my own function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xavjer's answer is correct, but you may want to remove the loop if you have a lot of markers:

```
Map<LatLng, Marker> map = ...;
```

and:

```
Marker marker = map.get(yourLatLng);
if (marker != null) {
    // just do it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
for( i=0;i<map.markers.length; i++ ) {
  var mlat = map.markers[i].position.lat();
  var mlng = map.markers[i].position.lng();
  if (mlat == yourGivenLat && mlng == yourGivenLng) {
    //do whatever you want
  }
}
```